# How to get an account that has updated the shared Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

**Premise**

We are monitoring the Google Calendar shared within the team.
Therefore, by combining "Trigger when changing calendar of Googe Apps Script" and Google Calendar API, we are creating a bot that notifies the creation, update, and deletion of events.

**Problem**

There are only two account information that can be obtained from Events.get of the Google Calendar API: the owner and the creator of the event.

([google-calendar-api/events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events))

So if account A created an event and account B edited it, there is currently no way to get B's information.
Please let us know if there is a way to get information about the account that updated the event in the shared Google Calendar, which includes the API and other services.

**code**

```
function doMain(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
  var items = onCalendarEdit(e.calendarId);

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var Event = Calendar.Events.get(e.calendarId, items[i].id);
    EventProcessing(Event);
  }
}



function onCalendarEdit(CalId) {
  var calendarId = CalId 
  var summary = Calendar.Calendars.get(calendarId).summary
  var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var nextSyncToken = properties.getProperty("syncToken_" + summary);
  var optionalArgs = {
    syncToken: nextSyncToken
  };
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(events));
  var nextSyncToken = events["nextSyncToken"];
  properties.setProperty("syncToken_" + summary, nextSyncToken);
  return events.items;
}

function EventProcessing(Event) {
/* bot : Processing to throw a notification 
*/
}
```

Comment: I think you are treading on privet data i would be surprised if you could the information

Comment: If you are the admin you can retrieve the calendar events through [Calendar Audit Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/calendar), is that what you meant?